# How to find element using value member attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to Disable a row in gridview and make the check box disable using some condition:
For example:

```
if (row["Islicense"].toString() == "false") {
   // disable the row and checkbox 
}
```

Here the identity id is "valuemember"

Below is the HTML for your reference:

```html
<table class="grid_table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 35px;">
        <col style="width: 150px;">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr valuemember="2" id="row_SelectedSiteId0" class="row_even">
            <td>
                <div class="bally-checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valuemember="1" id="row_SelectedSiteId1" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Asset</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="3" id="row_SelectedSiteId2" class="row_even"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Drop</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="9" id="row_SelectedSiteId3" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Accounting</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="7" id="row_SelectedSiteId4" class="row_even"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Slips</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="5" id="row_SelectedSiteId5" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Tickets</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the table row and detect the desired attribute, compare with your criteria and disable, or not the respective row.

In this case, you will disable every row that has a valuemember attribute equal to `yourCriteria`

jQuery

```
$('.grid_table tr').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   if (that.attr('valuemember') == 'yourCriteria') {
      that.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
      that.addClass('disabledRow');
   }
});
```

CSS

```
.disabledRow {
   opacity: 0.3
}
```

---

**DEMO (disable row with valuemember == 1)**

```js
$('.grid_table tr').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   if (that.attr('valuemember') == '1') {
      that.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
      that.addClass('disabledRow');
   }
});
```

```css
.disabledRow {
   opacity: 0.3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grid_table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 35px;">
        <col style="width: 150px;">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr valuemember="2" id="row_SelectedSiteId0" class="row_even">
            <td>
                <div class="bally-checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valuemember="1" id="row_SelectedSiteId1" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Asset</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="3" id="row_SelectedSiteId2" class="row_even"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Drop</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="9" id="row_SelectedSiteId3" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Accounting</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="7" id="row_SelectedSiteId4" class="row_even"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Slips</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr><tr valuemember="5" id="row_SelectedSiteId5" class="row_odd"><td><div class="bally-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bally-datagrid-select" id="actualcheckbox_SelectedSiteId"><span></span></label></div></td><td>Tickets</td><td class="cell-last">Recovery completed on 5/4/2015 12:43:51 PM</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One issue is still there.There is row selected event , so when ever i  am clicking the particular row, i am able to check the check box, even the property of check box is disable=true. So any suggestion.  I did 
for row disable :
that.find("td").unbind('click');
for check  box disable :
that.find('input,checkbox').prop("disabled", true);
Still not woking

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 if($('tr[valuemember="0"]').length){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid_table tr').each(function() {
   var attr = $(this).attr('valuemember');
  if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    // has valuemember attribute
  }
});
```